# Scope $destroy event called when initializing new controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently working on a project using Angular JS where i need to be able to initialize and destroy controllers and scopes to be able to show different content in the same modal. The problem i have encountered is that when i have compiled the new controller, the $destroy event is triggered instantly and therefore all my watchers on the scope are destroyed.

Controller 1

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.model = { name: 'World' };
    $scope.name = "Felipe";
    var DOM = '<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">{{model}}<input type="text" ng-model="model.name"/></div>';
    var newScope = $scope.$new();
    var elem = $compile(DOM)(newScope);
    $('#test1').append(elem);
});
```

Controller 2 that is being inserted

```
app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = { name: 'World2' };
    $scope.name = "Felipe2";
    $scope.$watch('$destroy', function() {
        $('#errorMessage').html('Scope was destroyed');
        console.log('destroyed scope');
    });
});
```

html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="test1"></div>
    <div id="errorMessage"></div>
</body>
```

I have reproduced the error in a minimal [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wh3fmr0xNgpeP34xNH7y?p=preview), where the text "Scope was destroyed" is showed in the result when $destroy has been called on the inserted controllers' scope.

Appreciate any help / workarounds to solve this issue, or guidelines for how i should have gone about it from the beginning.

Comment: Manipulating DOM in the controller is a bad practice and what do you mean by "to be able to show different content in the same modal"? Do you mean something like you click button 1 and it shows something, close the modal and click button two and it shows something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not destroying the controller. You are watching for `$destroy`, so it triggers the watch when `$destroy` property on the scope is initialized as a part of controller instantiation. Correct way to listen to the destroy event is using `$on`.

```
   $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $('#errorMessage').html('Scope was destroyed');
    console.log('destroyed scope', arguments);
   });
```

Comment: Awesome, knew it was something like that,  thanks :)

Comment: @Oreflow you are welcome.. One more think i want to mention is that, you dont want to do any DOM manipulations in the controller. Controller mostly is just for managing the viewmodel to render your view and possibly any business logic... Generally if you use angular correctly you wont have to do too many DOM manipulations yourself, but there are definitely cases where you need to where you should be using directives.